# How to tell a batch script where another script is?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I have a script that I can run in the command line to get me the version of software. It works perfectly in the command line. I type this in `getversion "<full path>"` and it gets me exactly what I need.

Now the catch is that I have to have the getversion.bat and a vbscript file both in the directory that I'm in for the command line. This is probably a dumb question but if I want to add this into a batch script where the version is set as a variable how would I do that?

right now I had it looking like this

```
@echo off
set version=getversion "<full path>"
echo %version%
pause>nul
```

The problem seems to be that the batch file doesn't know where to find getversion.bat or the vbscript referenced in that script. How can I tell the batch file where they are?

Comment: Use `for /f` to launch another script or program and capture its output to a variable.  `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('getversion "full path"') do set "version=%%I"`

Comment: How can I get around the fact that I'm running all of these from folders in a server? I keep getting this message `UNC paths are not supported`.

Comment: `pushd \\servername\path\to\file\ ` and then `'local\path\to\getversion filename.ext'`, and `popd` when done.

Comment: is that in lieu of the `"<full path>"`

Comment: Yep.  `pushd` creates a temporary drive mapping of UNC paths (mapping to `Z:` or whatever is available).  Just let `pushd` create the temporary drive assignment, then interact with the file as if it were local.  `popd` to kill the drive mapping.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to direct the output of your function to a file and then read this output back into a local variable using a `SET /P` command. This should do it:

```
SET TempFile="%Temp%\%RANDOM%.txt"

REM Direct output to a temp file.
CALL getversion "<full path>">%TempFile%

REM Read the output written to the temp file into a local variable.
SET /P Version=<%TempFile%

ECHO %Version%

REM Cleanup.
IF EXIST %TempFile% DEL %TempFile%
```

Alternately (and this way much "cleaner"), you can use a `FOR` command to run your function and store the output into a local variable:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`CALL getversion "<full path>"`) DO SET Version=%%A
ECHO %Version%
```

Comment: How can I get around the fact that I'm running all of these from folders in a server? I keep getting this message `UNC paths are not supported.`

Comment: The very first thing that pops up in cmd.exe. I have to run these scripts all from an external server. SO I get `CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory` and because of that the getversion.bat isn't recognized

Comment: @David - Your original question noted that `getversion` was working perfectly. How are you calling it currently on the remote server? You should be able to call it the same way to get the same result. My response just utilizes the output which you indicated was returning successfully.

Comment: haha well when I said working perfectly, I guess what I should have said is that it is working perfectly when I run getversion from the command line with it and the vbscript on my local machine it works fine

Comment: @David - You could try appending the full path to `getversion` (e.g. `\\Server\Path\To\getversion "full path"`). HOWEVER, if `getversion` is dependent on it being _executed_ on the respective server then this whole approach will not work as the batch/VB script will only execute respective to the local machine, regardless of where the source script is located.